# UWP App CosmosDb Contructor Throwing Error

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-cosmosdb, visual-studio-2019

I have a error which I have not seen before.
In my CosmosDb DocumentClient constructor:

```
docClient = new DocumentClient(new 
  Uri("https://docdb.documents.azure.com:443/"),
    "key_here",new ConnectionPolicy { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct, 
        ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp });
```

When I set a breakpoint it throws this error:

```
 A type initializer threw an exception. To determine which type, 
 inspect the InnerException's StackTrace property.
```

The InnerException's Stacktrace:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 
'DocumentDB.LogStoreViewer.dll!FreeIOManager' 
for method 'System.Int32 


Microsoft.Azure.Documents.LogStoreViewerInterop.
LogStoreViewerInteropWrapper.
FreeIOManager(System.IntPtr)'.
Calling this method would throw exception at runtime. Please make sure the 
P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, 
or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your 
P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, 
please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand 
the implications of using non-UWP APIs.
```

In my project I am referencing a .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library. According the error info it looks like

```
 Microsoft.Azure.Documents.LogStoreViewerInterop.
 LogStoreViewerInteropWrapper.
 FreeIOManager(System.IntPtr)'.
```

I can not find this to remove it or understand what it does so not sure how to cure this evil thing.

Comment: Are you using the [DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/) or [DocumentDB.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core/) package and which version?

Comment: I am using DocumentDb.Core